# Info on this Bunnell J-38 key

Tags: cw

I've been trying to find manufacturing date info on the J.H. Bunnell key ("J.H. Bunnell&Co" is stamped on top of the frame), but it seems to be somewhat unique. Most J-38 keys that I've found online have a binding strap that is bolted to the top of the frame, but this one is bound by the LINE binding post instead.

On the bottom is a white stamp that seems to show "SC 16 k", I'm not sure about the "k". So maybe 1916, or maybe this key has a bakelite base stolen from another manufacturer?

Appreciate any help identifying this key.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be an inspector's stamp.  It's not uncommon for such a stamp to include the inspector's initials along with a plant number, date code, or lot number.  Guessing it was stamped by someone whose initials are "SC."

Comment: Yes, an inspection stamp. My take on it was SC means Signal Corps and 18 was the inspector himself.